# class 'wphpc_PAnD' not found

Tags: php, warnings

> **PHP Warning:**  `call_user_func_array()` expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class `wphpc_PAnD` not found in `/var/www/clients/client32/web3288/web/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php` on line 288

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually caused by a filter or an action not properly declared. Somewhere in your theme or plugins is a line like:

```php
add_filter( 'hook_name' , array( 'wphpc_PAnD', 'someMethod' ) );
// or
add_action( 'hook_name' , array( 'wphpc_PAnD', 'methodName' ) );
```

which register class method with hook for a action or filter, but this class (**`wphpc_PAnD`**) does not exist.
Check if file with class definition is included and there is no typo in the class name in `add_action()` / `add_filter()`.